# Getting an int from a list

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I am trying to get an int out of a sqlite database in python. The output I recieve is [('29',)] I need the output to be 29. I have tried

```
Data = Int(Data)
```

But I get the error: name 'Data' is not defined

Comment: Consider showing some code around that sql query.

Comment: Is it stored as an integer or a string?

Comment: It is stored as an integer. And I would show more code but I don't have internet and I'm on mobile so it would be a lot of code to type on my phone.

Comment: @bereal I also didn't show code around the SQL query because that wasn't an issue and it wouldn't have helped to find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you receive more than 1 value from the DB?
For example Data = [('29', '12', '1',)]

If yes I would advise to use map:

```
Data = map(int, Data[0])
```

And if you receive, let say:
Data = [('29',), ('12',), ('1',)]

```
Data = map(int, [x[0] for x in Data])
```

Comment: As you already have a list comprehension, `map` is redundant:  `[int(x[0]) for x in Data]`.

Comment: I only need to receive 1 value. With your code I get an error later on in the script where I multiply the value from the database with another number. The error is unsupported operant type for *: int and map

Comment: @bereal that gives me [29]. Any way to remove the [ ]?

Comment: @TonyC are you asking how to get the first element from a list?

Comment: @bereal sorry for not being clear. But the code for the SQL query will only return 1 result. So there is only 1 element in the list

Comment: @TonyC that does not change much, the only element is still first. You have a string which is the first element of a tuple which is the first element of a list, so it's `int(Data[0][0])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Data = int(Data[0][0])
```

should work.

Comment: I get the error: int() argument must be a string or a number, not a 'tuple'